# How to get folder by sharepoint shared link

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, .net-core-3.1

I have link to sharepoint folder like https:///:x:/s//EcEHhjfer8tBhw84D4iadQUBdCcX_MGw-EpH_lQwXUPJjw?e=pBgWZS.

How can i get folder(eg. file list) using CSOM?

For files I've used something like this:

```
var file = context.Web.GetFileByUrl(sharedLink);
context.Load(file);
await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

but for folders I've found any suitable method.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no available method which could  get folder by Sharing Link in CSOM.

It only support to use ServerRelativeUrl:

```
context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared%20Documents/Folder1")
```

I suggest you can submit a UserVoice in SharePoint Online Development Platform here:

[SharePoint Dev Platform](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform)